# Yocto recipe for Nodejs V8.3 or newer

Tags: node.js, yocto

I'm trying to add nodejs support for my yocto environment to be able to compile react native code.
I found a recipe here: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-nodejs/
maximum version offered in above link is 7.10.0, but react native needs 8.3 or newer. How to get recipe for Nodejs 8.3 or newer.

Comment: [meta-oe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_10.16.0.bb?h=master) already contains 10.16.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

Current OpenEmbedded master already contains [v10.16.0](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_10.16.0.bb?h=master), whereas meta-nodejs should be considered deprecated. So depending on the exact release you are on give or take a little, but as you can see from the [log](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/log/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/nodejs), v8.4 is available since 2017-08-31.

Comment: The Current OpenEmbedded master doesn't provide the npm-base class, which provides oe_runnpm to call npm within the bitbake recipes. Is there an other way to call npm? I can't find any documentaion or examples for the new nodejs recipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PREFERED_VERSION_nodejs="8.3"` in your local.conf file